# How to handle product/subproduct in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am making a proof of concept for an app, using Rails 4 and Postgresql. I am thinking on the best way to handle the relation between Products and SubProducts. 
A Product have a name, a description... and a SubProduct could have multiple fields too.
A Product have many SubProduct, a SubProduct belongs to one Product.

I have some Products and SubProducts with hundreds of fields. So I think it is best to not use STI to avoid thousands of null value.

Also I am working with remote designers, I would like to keep it simple for them. So when they want to display the value of a field from a sub product, they would write something like @product.name (from Product table) or @product.whatever (field from SubProduct table).

My question is how to handle this ? For the moment, I was thinking to delete the Products table and to make multiple SELECT to db, one for each SubProducts table. But maybe there is a solution to keep the Products table ? Or maybe I can take advantage of table inheritance from Postgresql ?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the hundreds of fields all different for each subproduct? (As you mentioned, ["sparse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#Modeling_sparse_attributes) attributes can lead to lots of nulls.)

This brings to mind an entity-attribute-value model, as described here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Here's a presentation with one organization's solution (key/value [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)):

https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/3/37/Eav-pgconfnyc2014.pdf

This can quickly get very complicated, and makes things like search much more challenging.

And if there are many variations, this also brings to mind a semi-structured, document-oriented or "NoSQL" design.

Comment: Most of SubProducts fields are different. It is a legacy database, but I am Ok to create a new structure. The thing is I am not sure of the best solution in Rails.